# How can I transform a Variable from main.c to another file ( interrupt handler)

Tags: c, variables, embedded, global

I'm working on a new project, I want to write my own protocol. Therefore I have to transform a variable (from main.c) to an interrupt handler file.

this is my IRQHandler.h file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef stm32f4xx_EXTI0_IRQHAndler_H 
#define stm32f4xx_EXTI0_IRQHAndler_H 
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void);
#endif
```

this is my IRQHandler.C File:

```
    void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if(GPIOA->IDR & 0x0001){

        USART_SendData(USART1, ConvertedValue);

              // GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12);

    EXTI_ClearFlag(EXTI_Line0);
    // EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
  }

  EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
}
```

And the requisite variable is Converted Value, what is in the main file.. and I can't transform... I know it's a reallly easy problem... but I can't solve it now..

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Posting the code you have in main.c would help - or at least the declaration of `ConvertedValue`. "transform" is not the correct word.  All you need to do is make the variable accessible/visible cross-modules. There is no "transformation" required.

Comment: Use .c rather than .C as the file extension.  Some compilers (GCC for example) will compile a .C file as C++.

Comment: I think you mean "transfer" or "access", rather than "transform".

Answer (score 2):

In IRQHandler.c

```
#include "IRQHandler.h"

volatile uint8_t ConvertedValue ;

void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Then create IRQHandler.h with:

```
#if !defined IRQHandler_INCLUDE
#define IRQHandler_INCLUDE

extern volatile uint8_t ConvertedValue ;

#endif
```

Then in main.c

```
#include "IRQHandler.h"

int main()
{
    ConvertedValue = getValue() ; // or whatever - Converted value is visible/accessible here.
}
```

Alternatively of course you can define `ConveretedValue` in main.c and declare it as an external in IRQHandler.c (whether directly or via a header file is your choice - a header file as I have used is preferable as it allows the compiler to perform the type checking.

Comment: You should have `volatile` on header file variable declaration too.

Comment: @user694733 : Thanks - the compiler would have spotted that.